# How to recover? Suspended google Adwords account

Tags: google-ads-api, double-click-advertising, google-advertising-id, pay-per-click

Account was suspended on 23 jan (saying i have done Misrepresentation)

after follow ups,

23 feb they sent email saying (suspicious behaviour in the payment activity of this or your other AdWords accounts)

later they sent email saying (We’ve confirmed that your account is in violation of our AdWords policies)

further more saying (Please avoid creating additional AdWords accounts, as they will be subjected to the same suspension).

Can some one advise what to do? the point is our card is in use with multiple accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Google are pretty thorough with their investigations, so if something is in violation, then it probably is! Have you tried contacting your account management team? I believe all accounts are assigned to an account management team, and then assigned to teams based on spend limits. Visit [this link](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6381844?from=cuf_billing_nota) for contact numbers.

Your best bet is to give AdWords support a call and provide your account IDs and find out who your account manager is, and then query the violation with them and try to get them remove the suspension.

You could try opening a new account with new card details if its a payment issue, but your domain will match from an existing account so Google will figure this out pretty quickly, therefore its best to resolve any violations directly with Google rather than trying to beat around the system.

I would recommend creating a [manager account](https://adwords.google.com/home/tools/manager-accounts/) and then adding accounts under the manager account, this way all accounts can use one billing method as opposed to setting the same billing in individual accounts.

Comment: Last email they sent and said no one can help any further, the violation is that our company card have been in use on multiple account.